# Output votes to div dynamically in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I can´t get the correct output for the corresponding div on each post.
How can I pass in the corresponding post id when clicking the button?
This is an AJAX-request via jQuery.

template.php

```
          $votes = get_post_meta($post->ID, "votes", true);
          $votes = ($votes == "") ? 0 : $votes;


          echo '<div id="vote_counter">'. $votes.'</div><br>';
```

voteme.js

```
 jQuery(document).ready( function() {

 jQuery(".user_vote").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    post_id = $(this).attr("data-post_id");
    nonce = $(this).attr("data-nonce");

 jQuery.ajax({
     type : "post",
     dataType : "json",
     url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
     data : {action: "my_user_vote", post_id : post_id, nonce: nonce},
     success: function(response) {
        if(response.type == "success") {
           jQuery("#vote_counter").html(response.vote_count);
        }
        else {
           alert("Your vote could not be added");
        }


     }

   });   

 });
   return false; 
});
```

functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );

function my_script_enqueuer() {
   wp_register_script( "my_voter_script", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/voteme.js', array('jquery') );
   wp_localize_script( 'my_voter_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));        

   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my_voter_script' );

}

add_action("wp_ajax_my_user_vote", "my_user_vote");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_my_user_vote", "my_must_login");

function my_user_vote() {

   if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], "my_user_vote_nonce")) {
      exit("No naughty business please");
   }   

   $vote_count = get_post_meta($_REQUEST["post_id"], "votes", true);
   $vote_count = ($vote_count == '') ? 0 : $vote_count;
   $new_vote_count = $vote_count + 1;

   $vote = update_post_meta($_REQUEST["post_id"], "votes", $new_vote_count);

   if($vote === false) {
      $result['type'] = "error";
      $result['vote_count'] = $vote_count;
   }
   else {
      $result['type'] = "success";
      $result['vote_count'] = $new_vote_count;
   }

   if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
      $result = json_encode($result);
      echo $result;
   }
   else {
      header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
   }

   die();

}

function my_must_login() {
   echo "You must log in to vote";
   die();
}
```

Comment: What's the failure or specific question to be answered?

Comment: The output in the div updates the first div in the first post. I am trying to output the vote from the current id to the corresponding post. echo '<div id="vote_counter">'. $votes.'</div><br>';

Comment: The question is: How do I output the value to the corresponding div? I have tried looping in php but I think that jQuery will select the element for me.

Comment: I know I cant access the same id in jQuery but change to classes to access them all. But I think the solution is to loop through all the corresponding post ids in PHP and output accordingly.

Comment: I have changed the id in the div to a class but it outputs, as expected, to all divs. My objective is to output according to data-post_id which I have also added to the div. But since it is one div with one class it doesn't output accordingly. How do I achieve this? Any suggestions would be appreciated since I have been stuck for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT] *Provided better replacements.*

Try this:

In *template.php*, replace:

```
echo '<div id="vote_counter">'. $votes.'</div><br>';
```

..with:

```
echo '<div id="vote_counter-' . $post->ID . '" class="vote_counter">'. $votes.'</div><br>';
```

In *voteme.js*, replace:

```
jQuery("#vote_counter").html(response.vote_count);
```

..with:

```
jQuery("#vote_counter-" + post_id).html(response.vote_count);
```

You should also declare `post_id` and `nonce` as local variables; i.e.:

```
var post_id = $(this).attr("data-post_id"),
  nonce = $(this).attr("data-nonce");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'd swap the `id` and `class` on the `<div>`: `echo '<div class="vote_counter" id="vote_counter-' . $post->ID . '">'`{...} . IIRC, `id`s should be unique on the page, but `class`es  can be re-used.

Comment: @PatJ, yes you're right. I'd actually do the same, but perhaps I temporarily forgot that.. or was a bit confused. Thanks! =)

Comment: That did the trick! I tried several outputs but nothing worked. Thanks again! This is very useful!

Comment: @tc2049 You're welcome! And don't forget to upvote or accept the answer.. =)

Comment: Done! I am a newbie here but I will upvote it when I have 15 in rep.